# JavaScript isNaN function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using isNan functionto check if entered value is a number:

```
if(isNaN(num)) {
    alert('I am not a number');
}
else {
//
     }
```

However, if entered value is, for example, "5748hh" it is understandable like a number and return `false`. What is wrong?

Comment: You need to correctly close your parenthesis in this example :) You're missing a closing ) after num).

Comment: `isNaN("5748hh") === true;` What's not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from Mozilla MDN

> When the argument to the isNaN function is not a number, the value is first coerced to a number. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is NaN. Thus for non-numbers that when coerced to numeric type result in a valid non-NaN numeric value (notably the empty string and boolean primitives, which when coerced give numeric values zero or one), the "false" returned value may be unexpected;  the empty string, for example, is surely "not a number." The confusion stems from the fact that the term, "not a number", has a specific meaning for numbers represented as IEEE-794 floating-point values. The function should be interpreted as answering the question, "is this value, when coerced to a numeric value, an IEEE-794 'Not A Number' value?"

so `alert(isNaN('45345ll'))` returns true because its value coercion is different than a `parseInt/parseFloat` conversion.

e.g.

```
var num = false;
console.log(isNaN(num));        /* return false because the coerced value is 0 but */
console.log(parseInt(num, 10)); /* return isNaN */
```

Maybe you get an unexpected value due to a missing paren in your `if` statement

Answer (score 2):

You must try to parse it first:

```
if(isNaN(parseInt(num, 10))) {
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN):

> Since the very earliest versions of the isNaN function specification, its behavior for non-numeric arguments has been confusing. **When the argument to the isNaN function is not a number, the value is first coerced to a number**. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is NaN. Thus for non-numbers that when coerced to numeric type result in a valid non-NaN numeric value (notably the empty string and boolean primitives, which when coerced give numeric values zero or one)

Unlike `parseInt()` this *coerced to a number* will result in Not a Number for string like `5748hh` and hence the behavior you see.

Comment: This actually returns a valid number 5748 from string "5478hh".

Comment: @zvona the OP said *"5748hh" it **is understandable like a number*** so from this I understood the sample string should give back the number `5748`.

Comment: @ShadowWizard a coercion is different than a conversion so `5748aa`is not *coerced* as a number and it don't give back a number. see my example below

Comment: @ShadowWizard, true indeed. I missed that line and understood OP wanted the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

if you parse a string that starts with a number it will successfully parse into the number, with the remainder of the string ignored.  e.g. `parseInt('56sadfh', 10)` will parse into `56`.  If you want to prevent this you should use a regex to check the input instead. e.g.

```
if (!num.match(/[0-9]+/)) {
  alert("not a number");
}
```

Comment: @Raynos I don't understand your comment. What do you mean?

Comment: `parseInt('56sadfh', 10) === 56`, `+'56sadfh' is NaN` thus `isNan(+'56sadfh')` works

Comment: I didn't say it didn't work...  I was advocating a completely different approach to checking the validity of a number.

Comment: I'm advocating that `+str` is far more elegant then `str.match(regex)`

Comment: In all seriousness I don't agree.  It'd require a comment explaining it, as it's not exactly a well known feature of JS, hardly a sign of elegance. It might be quicker, but not more elegant.  Also `str.match(regex)` is portable, can be used to validate other formats by changing the regex. Leading to more code re-use and fewer special cases.

Answer (score 0):

`isNaN("5748hh");` returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it gives me true.

```
alert(isNaN("123hh"));  // - alert true.
```

see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dkrg8/) JSfiddler

Answer (score 0):

In my Firebug:

```
>>> isNaN("5748hh")
true
```

Answer (score 0):

isNaN = is Not a Number, so if it returns true the data inputted is not a number.

http://jsfiddle.net/8fMAr/

```
if(isNaN("5748hh"))
{
    alert("not a number");
}
else
{
    alert("a number");   
}
```

Returns true: "not a number", like it should.

Answer (score 0):

NaN is a special number.
isNaN(argument) function checks the argument if it is a NaN value, but it also gives true if the argument is a string, representing a valid integer.